# Need help errors in Unity for building an AR app

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am very new to Unity and cannot find proper guidance resources for what I want to build. I have attached a screenshot of the errors that are present in the very simple code I had put in, and I need help with how to resolve them. I cannot move forward without resolving these, and I have a deadline.
Anyone with experience in Unity is welcome; it is a very important project.

[image: The errors that Unity shows]

I had 2 Sketchfab plugins, one of which was the old version. I have tried to eliminate that package, but I still cannot eliminate the errors. I still think the errors are because of some build settings I have because the tutorial I am following did not specify which I should use, and I have tried them all, out of which this one was working remotely okay.

Comment: **[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)**

Comment: **[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)**